# DotNetOpenAuth WebConsumer not redirecting to OAuth provider in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, google-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC app in which I am trying to have use DotNetOpenAuth for my Google OAuth. I am using the GoogleConsumer class from the sample, and attempting to do the first step of the authentication. The code below is essentially the same as that in the provided WebForms application, just in an MVC controller:

```
public string Authenticate()
{
  GoogleTokenManager tokenManager = new GoogleTokenManager(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
  WebConsumer webConsumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumer.ServiceDescription, tokenManager);
  GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(webConsumer, GoogleConsumer.Applications.Gmail);
  return "";
}
```

The code executes when I make an AJAX request to the controller, but I am never redirected to the Google page for authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying request was returning a 302 redirect response which I wasn't handling properly. What I found to be more helpful was to specify the callback URL to another action in my controller, as follows:

```
public ActionResult Authenticate()
{
  string callbackUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("Authenticate", "OtherAction");
  Uri callback = new Uri(callbackUrl);

  WebConsumer webConsumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumer.ServiceDescription, TokenManager);
  Dictionary<string, string> extraParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  extraParameters.Add("scope", GoogleConsumer.GetScopeUri(GoogleConsumer.Applications.Gmail));

  UserAuthorizationRequest request = webConsumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, extraParameters, null);
  return webConsumer.Channel.PrepareResponse(request).AsActionResult();
}

public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
  // oauth_verifier, oauth_token are now in the RequestQueryString
}
```